# How to use field widths with printf and Term::ANSIColor?

Tags: perl

How can correctly left-justify (within a field of fixed length) a color string using [`Term::ANSIColor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor)? Here is a sample program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $str1 = "Hello";
my $str2 = (color("bold red") . $str1 . color("reset"));

printf "%-10s : ok\n", $str1;
printf "%-10s : ok\n", $str2;
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output: I would like the `"ok"` fields to be vertically aligned.

Comment: Best Practice would have the coloration as part of the Template and not the Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is that when you add colour to the str2, it casues the string to be prefixed with chars before the word which set the colour and then postfixed with chars after the word to reset the color. When you print these, of course you dont see these extra chars. As your shell interprets them and prints only the string text in the color you chose.

we can see the length of each string here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ANSIColor;


my $str1 = "Hello";
my $str2 = (color("bold red") . $str1 . color("reset"));

print "length of str1 is: ", length($str1), "\n";
print "length of str2 is: ", length($str2), "\n";

printf "%-10s : ok\n", $str1;
printf "%-10s : ok\n", $str2;
```

**Output**

```
length of str1 is: 5
length of str2 is: 16
Hello      : ok
Hello : ok
```

When your `printf` evaluates the length of `$str2` it sees it as 16, since this is larger than 10 then it sees no need to pad it with any spaces.

So as @tjd said in his comment you would need to rethink your approach to put the colour in the formatting rather than putting it in the data its self

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle! This seems like the way to do it yes. But I think `printf` could have done this as well. Shouldn't it be easy for `printf` to determine which characters actually are printable and not?

Comment: @HåkonHægland These are printable chars, its just that your terminal is interpreting them. If we take a simple example from unix shell. `echo "\033[31mHello\033[32m World!\033[m"`. this will print hello in red and world in green then reset back to the normal color. As you can see you can read all the chars in this text and they are all printable. its just that the terminal interprets and strips them out. but printf has no way to know thats what you intended to use this string for

Comment: Yes you are probably right.. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to apply the color sequences *after* the `printf` instead of before:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Term::ANSIColor;

my $format = '%-10s';

my @greetings = (
    sprintf($format, 'Hello'),
    sprintf($format, 'Greetings')
);

foreach my $greeting (@greetings) {
    say colored($greeting, 'bold red') . ' : ok';
    say "$greeting : ok";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Hello      : ok
Hello      : ok
Greetings  : ok
Greetings  : ok
```

(with the first `Hello` and first `Greetings` in color, of course)

You can also use [`Text::Aligner`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Aligner), which knows how to interpret the color sequences generated by `Term::ANSIColor`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Term::ANSIColor;
use Text::Aligner qw(align);

my @greetings = qw(Hello Greetings);

my @lines;
foreach my $greeting (@greetings) {
    push @lines, colored($greeting, 'bold red') . ' : ok';
    push @lines, "$greeting : ok";
}

say for align(qr/:/, @lines);
```

#### Output:

```
    Hello : ok
    Hello : ok
Greetings : ok
Greetings : ok
```

(again, with the first `Hello` and first `Greetings` in color)

Note that this aligns everything on the colons, so you won't get the left-justified output you asked for, but is another alternative to think about.